# How to use output of code?

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, dictionary, output

The code below gives the output of `screenId` and count of each `screenId`.

Once a `screenId` gets to a certain count say 10 I would like to perform an action. 
Would I be using an "If" statement? 
New to all this and not sure how to get started here.

Thank you!

```
 NSCountedSet *totalScans = [NSCountedSet setWithArray:appDelegate.scannedNumbers]; 
    NSMutableArray *dictArray = [NSMutableArray array]; 
    for (NSNumber *num in totalScans) { 
        NSDictionary *dict = @{@"screenId":num, 
               @"count":@( [totalScans countForObject:num] )}; 
               [dictArray addObject:dict]; 
    } 

    NSArray *final = 
       [dictArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:
            @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"ScreenId" ascending:YES]]]; 

    NSLog(@"%@",final);
```

Console Output:

```
count = 7; 
screenId = 2402E58B73513EFEE08F5DE; 

count = 6; 
screenId = 9DBC162802A290BD31107B6; 

count = 4; 
screenId = 9729C8A8C7DCFCBFEE1BFD6;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could. that's a recommended way of doing this. You could also use a switch statement, but at the end there's no difference. Add this code snippet inside your `for` loop:

```
if([totalScans countForObject:num] == 10){
   //Perform your action here.
}
```

Comment: Ok Thank you. With the If Statement it does == 10 for all screenId's. How would I go about doing it for each individual screenId? super appreciated!

Comment: @IanJames You should use it inside your for loop.

Comment: Thanks @ Gabriel. I got the If statement inside the For loop. I'm going to have a lot of different screenId's and each one may have a different "count" to perform an action. Could you advise the best way to go about it? I'm so close thank u!!

Comment: Hi Gabriel can you give an example of using the Switch statement? super appreciate it!